# The notion of "prose"

Tags: word-meaning, word-form

Is **prosaic** an adjective form of **prose**? I understand **prose** as just a way of writing, irrespective of whether a piece of writing is fiction or nonfiction, right? If so, an article from papers, a drama or a historical novel could be prose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, “prosaic” is an adjective form of “prose”. You are correct that something being categorized as prose has nothing to do with the subject matter.

> ### Prosaic
>
> #### Etymology
>
> From French *prosaïque*, from Medieval Latin *prosaicus* (“in prose”), from Latin *prosa* (“prose”), from *prorsus* (“straightforward, in prose”), from Old Latin *provorsus* (“straight ahead”), from *pro-* (“forward”) + *vorsus* (“turned”), from *vertō* (“to turn”), from Proto-Indo-European **wer-* (“to turn, to bend”).
>
> #### Adjective
>
> **prosaic** (*comparative* more **prosaic**, *superlative* most **prosaic**)
>
> 1. Pertaining to or having the characteristics of prose.*
>      
>    *The tenor of Eliot's **prosaic** work differs greatly from that of his poetry.*
> 2. (of writing or speaking) Straightforward; matter-of-fact; lacking the feeling or elegance of poetry.
>      
>    *I was simply making the **prosaic** point that we are running late.*
> 3. (usually of writing or speaking but also figurative) Overly plain or simple, to the point of being boring; humdrum.
>      
>    *His account of the incident was so **prosaic** that I nodded off while reading it.*
>      
>    *She lived a **prosaic** life.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Wiktionary entry for “prosaic”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosaic)
> * StoneyB points out that while this may be at the core of the word's derivation, this usage is extremely uncommon and should probably be avoided.</sub>

From the Latin roots you can see that “prosaic” not only has the same derivation as “prose”, it also literally means “straightforward”. The definitions that follow are all very closely related, but draw a lot from context, so when you encounter the word in the wild you'll need to decide just how figuratively it's being used.

Comment: If an article is written with lots of metaphor, irony, or any other rhetorical devices, can it still be considered as prose? @Tyler James Young

Comment: When you're making a literal distinction, the lines are pretty clear: either something is poetry or prose. If you are using prosaic figuratively (which is its more common use), then you would probably _not_ call that article **prosaic,** even though it is, technically, prose. In fact, the adjective forms “prosaic” and “poetic” are generally used figuratively to describe things that do _not_ fit the category they describe (prose or poetry), but nonetheless evoke the qualities of either straightforward description or lyrical beauty.

Comment: +1 But precisely because the core meaning of *prosaic* is "straightforward, everyday, boring", it is *very unusual* to find *prosaic* in the sense of *not poetic* - so rare that I would call it a mistake. The standard formal term for this is *prose*, employed either nominally or attributively: *Eliot's prose* or *Eliot's prose work*.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't think we understand each other. Care to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15192/discussion-between-tjy-and-stoneyb)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the adjectives 'poetic' and 'prosaic' have shifted in meaning from merely describing 'a poem/poetry' and 'prose' respectively.

'Poetic' has a meaning 'possessing the qualities or charm of poetry' (Random House online). Google Ngrams shows poetic language, form, justice, imagination, expression, diction, genius, art and feeling, of which perhaps only 'poetic form' is restricted to actual poetry. It is quite possible to have 'poetic prose' - goodreads.com has a list of '[Popular Poetic Prose Books](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/poetic-prose)'

'Prosaic' has a meaning 'commonplace or dull; matter-of-fact or unimaginative'. Google Ngrams shows prosaic world, life and age. It is quite possible to have 'prosaic poetry' (probably any poetry ever written by me!). goodreads.com does not have a list of 'prosaic poetry'!

While I was researching this answer, I also found '[The Unknown Nabokov, part 1: Poetic Prose or Prosaic Poetry?](http://www.3ammagazine.com/3am/the-unknown-nabokov-part-1-poetic-prose-or-prosaic-poetry/)' and '[Anzaldua's Prosaic poetry and poetic prose](http://prezi.com/bc0xkxs3hcnm/anzalduas-prosaic-poetry-and-poetic-prose/)'.

Answer (score 0):

The word prose can be regarded as a speech or a writing which goes straightforward, and usually is defined in opposition with poetry, as a form of oral discourse or writing, as a means of expression that is not subject to versification.

The prose is as a reaction against poetry, which using metaphorical means of expression and style “ornaments” doesn’t clarify the sense, but misappropriates the idea’s meaning.

Actually Molière, with his well-known irony defined the concept:

> ”[All that is not prose is verse; and all that is not verse is prose](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re)”.

B. Croce is among the first who differentiated the expression means of prose compared to those of poetry considering that these don’t express emotional feelings and sentiments but are directed to thoughtfulness.

Later, Roland Barthes defines the prose keeping the same idea: “a minimum discourse which conveys the thought in the most economical way”.

As far as prose’s content is concerned it can be: scientific, philosophic, belletristic, publicist, memoirist. Regarding the literary current manifested in the narrative composition of literary work the prose is romantic, realist, naturalist, sci-fi, etc.